# Obtener lista de elementos filtrados por id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

Por ejemplo, tengo dos tablas con relación 1_n (Intervalos tienen de una a muchas entregas) pero no soy capaz de listar las entregas relacionadas con el id de usuario específico filtrando en el controlador con la cláusula where. Intento lo siguiente pero no lista como debe, es decir me lista unos elementos y otros no.

**Tablas**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Controlador**

```
public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $datos = array(
            'title' => "entregas", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
            'username' => "Administrador"
        );

        $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);

        //Quitamos los botones de añadir y quitar
        $crud->unset_add();
        $crud->unset_edit();

        $crud->set_language("spanish");
        $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');
        $crud->set_table('entregas');



        $crud->where('idCarga =', $idCarga);



        $crud->display_as('idCarga', 'Nº Entrega');
        $crud->set_subject('Carga / Descarga'); 
        $crud->set_relation('idCarga', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');

        $crud->columns('fechaCita', 'horaCita', 'numeroEntrega', 'cliente', 'Origen', 'Destino', 'cargaPrevista', 'entregaPrevista', 'accion', 'estado');




        $output = $crud->render();




        $this->_example_output($output);


        //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/footer.php'  ------------- /
        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
    }




    function _example_output($output = null) {
        $this->load->view('example', (array) $output);
    }
```

Comment: Hola, creo que la línea `$crud->where('idCarga =', $idCarga);` es sin el simbolo `=` (`$crud->where('idCarga', $idCarga);`)

Comment: Lo he probado, tampoco va @PabloAlcantar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');

Comment: Gracias @Javi También probé con esta línea y sigue sin mostrarme lo añadido a ese intervalo horario

Comment: @javi por favor mejorar el nivel de tus respuestas. Si no estás seguro que sea una respuesta, agregalo como un comentario de la pregunta y si te indican que ayuda, genera una respuesta mejor elaborada. saludos

Comment: $crud->set_table('Entregas');
$crud->set_subject('Entrega');
 
$crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario','InetrvalosHorarios','intervaloHorario');
 
$output = $crud->render();

Comment: Prueba un ejemplo sencillo sin sentencia Where como ese a ver si funciona, si no va quizás es porque los campos están mal enlazados

Comment: @PabloAlcantar no me deja comentar lo puesto por otro, me dice que tengo que tener un mínimo de 50 puntos o noseque

Comment: Chicos disculpad, la respuesta de @Javi funciona perfectamente. Se me ocurrió que al haber intentado probar tanto antes, los ids ya estarían ocupados y por eso no mostraba lo que debía, de ahí que solo se mostraran algunos. Lo que hice fue limpiar la base de datos por completo y comenzar a utilizar la aplicación agregando campos y efectivamente, enlaza cada cual con su intervalo correspondiente. Muchas gracias por todo. Saludos!

Comment: Bueno pues parece que me adelanté a los acontecimientos, de los datos añadidos solo muestra el primer dato... pero algo es algo